# What does it mean when a sequence converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am currently learning how to write proofs in Math and I have a couple questions on sequences.

Question: Prove that if $\{a_n^2\}$ converges, then $\{a_n\}$ converges.

First, I assume that $\{a_n^2\}$ converges. My question is when you assume that a sequence converges, what can you say about it?

Suppose $L$ is the limit of $\{a_n^2\}$.

Can I say that the
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n^2-L|=0?$$
Because $\{a_n^2\}$ is getting very close to $L$.

Can some one clarify to me what does it mean when a sequence converge to a limit $L$?

Comment: This is not always true, if you don't specify in which set (with which topology) does $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ belongs. For example, consider $a_k=(\cos k,\sin k)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with usual Euclidean topology, then $a_k^2=1$ for all $k$ hence $(a_k^2)_k$ converges but not $(a_k)_k$.

Answer (score 3):

It means $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N >0, n > N \implies |a_n^2 - L| < \epsilon$.

While you can just write $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n^2 -L| = 0$, the statement is meaningful only when you know the meaning of limit.

The thing that you try to prove is false, try an alternating sequence where each term take the same absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

Simply consider
$$\begin{array}{}
a_n=(-1)^n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \\
\end{array}
$$
$a_n$ diverged, but $a^2_n$ converged.

But if we know, that $\exists \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a^2_n = L$, then $a^2_n \to L \Leftrightarrow |a^2_n-L| \to 0$.